# Poco SSL exception during https get request

Tags: c++, ssl, exception, poco

I've created a C++ app that uses the Poco libraries in order to make get https requests to a server. The code I use is quite simple :

```
const Context::Ptr ctx = new Context(Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "", Context::VERIFY_NONE, 9, false, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
HTTPSClientSession session(_uri.getHost(), _uri.getPort(), ctx);
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, path, HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
```

The code runs correctly and I get the 200 ok responses. After an amount of time I get the following Poco Exception consecutively :

```
"Poco Exception Code: 0 Name: SSL Exception"
```

I have the default timeout which is 60s I assume. Is this a timeout due to busy server which receives the request or something else? Is there anything I can with my code to minimize these events? I have also created an issue in the poco Github bug tracker, but can someone here give me a hint?

Comment: check send/receivetimeout of your poco websocket. set it to something higher

Comment: @MacGeek I added session.setTimeout(Poco::Timespan(90, 0)); but also got the consecutives poco exceptions after many successful https requests

Comment: I don't understand your comment are you in same situation as before?  with Timespan(90,0) you will have only valid connection for 90 seconds.

Comment: @MacGeek I have even with this timespan consecutive exception responses after a great deal of 200 oks responses. From the httpsession class I see that you can set either the timeout or set  connectionTimeout, sendTimeout,receiveTimeout in the same time. I chose the first which I assume prevails all the others.

Comment: I think what you are encountering is openssl lock error. Poco does not do well there. But they recently fixed that bug. What's your version of Poco?

Comment: @MacGeek My current version is 1.7.8p2

Comment: Ye. That version has that bug. I am not near my laptop. So I will just give you clue where to look. Openssl has a global lock. One needs to keep track of those global locks. Probably you are using openssl for something else to in your code but you don't track it. So poco and your code don't go along

Comment: @MacGeek thanks for your help. It would be very helpful to know since which version of Poco this bug has been fixed.

Comment: This is the bug you are most probably facing. 
https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/1160
According to bug report it is fixed in 1.8.2 (yet to be released)

Comment: Have you found out the solution?